# Work with generic

Tags: c#, generic-programming

I have a class look like this:

```
public class NamSetup: INameSetup
{
     static List<Name> nbames= new List<Name>();
     ....
     public List<Name> GetClients()
        {
            return names;
        }

     public List<Name> AddName(Name name)
     {
        names.Add(name);
        return GetClients();
     }
 }
```

I just want to make another class with names: myName.cs
Inside myName.cs and want to call the AddName methode above. Do you know to to do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't understand where's the problem ...

Comment: I don't understand too. But I guess he just wants to call AddName() method from other classes.

Comment: Yes. I want to call AddName() method from other class

Answer (score 0):

```
 class MyName
 {
    public MyName()
    { 
        NamSetup nm = new NamSetup(); 
        nm.AddName(new Name());
    }
 }
```

Comment: That what exactly what I am doing. But I get a error: "Type name expected, but namespace name found". It is some thing I miss in using...?

Comment: do you have basic knowledge about C# (or java)?

Comment: You have a namespace that is the same as the class you are creating. This is causing the conflict. Either change the name of your namespace or class so they don't conflict.